# How can I install 2 Linux distributions but boot into one by default?

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub

is there a way to have 2 Linux distributions installed but make it so it boots into one by default until I do something while booting (For example press F10 or something). I know about grub, but it makes me choose between the two every time I boot. For example when I have Mint and Ubuntu installed on two partitions I want it to boot into Ubuntu unless I do something while it's booting.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not what you're looking for but anyway;
GRUB has an option for a timer to count down and then load whichever os is selected. If you have your default os as the first item and set your timer to something fairly short then it will act just  as you've described, then if you want your other os you can press an arrow at the grub menu and change to the other one.

Edit:
In /etc/default/grub 
There are values for ' GRUB_TIMEOUT '
Which will set the timer value

Comment: To make your answer better you should provide the option in question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility called **grub-customizer** in the Ubuntu repositories that allows to manage all the boot process, maybe with some setting you can do what you are telling us.
Link of the program: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

Answer (score 0):

You are rebooting your system each time your switch Linux distributions - so why not use your firmware boot manager to do what you want to do.

Comment: Boot priority settings won't help in this case. They work if you dual boot it with WIndows. If both the dual boot OS are linux then they will prompt you to grub first no matter which gets the boot priority.

Comment: Well, selecting which distribution to boot works fine for me using the UEFI boot menu.  Mind you, I stopped using GRUB2  years ago when EFISTUB booting became available.